# Please help identify traditional Chinese painting

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I've inherited a Chinese cloth painting from my ancestors. I'd be grateful if you could help me know more about the artwork through the signature and seal.

[image: signature]

[(Full artwork)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIZet.jpg)

Comment: Well, my best guess is 歡敬 - I'll let more expert people answer.

Comment: It seems like 名家 to me.

Comment: @blackgreen @user3306356♦ as per [this meta post](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1622/what-does-this-say-type-question-policy-for-seals-and-calligraphy), we have currently decided to make an exception for these kinds of questions. Let's be consistent in our policies - voice your opposition there to allowing these kinds of questions to be posted without effort if you have strong opinions on the matter.

Comment: @dROOOze Yeah, I just figured this one was past its sell by when it showed up on the queue.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from the seal script, the left character is either 歡 [image] or 觀 [image] (from 趙孟頫 as well). I can't guess which one because the top-right part is blurred. As for the right-hand side one, I don't know much, but I'd say that there is either the radical 羽 which looks like [image] or [image], or the radical 羊 [image]  (趙孟頫) (if we don't consider the seal's border as an integral part) in seal script. I can't identify the component between them so that the whole character makes sense to me, but  @dROOOze's guess looks like the most meaningful ([歡敬](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AD%A1%E6%95%AC)): [image]. However, the lack of the right-hand side component 攵 of 敬 in the picture makes me doubtful.

Concerning the cursive script above, I agree with @Asule's answer which is justifiable: 觀[image] 我 [image] (趙孟頫).

Answer (score 0):

They are "观我", which means "look at me". My grandfather is a professional calligrapher. He writes lots of different works. And I learned a lot from him. Thank you.

Comment: "Appreciate" is a more accurate translation than "look at" for "观".

Answer (score 0):

It could be 茗家. It seems to me that there is something above the 名.

As for the seal, my best bet is 歡都. There are many parts that are not really clear or overlap, so I'm not too sure for that.

Answer (score 0):

The "signature" is 观我 guan1 wo3; the seal is 昨观 zuo2 guan1.
However, both of them does not tell anything about the identity of the artist.